# Python 3.6 reading csv file and using floats as dict keys

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am working on a first ever python script to read a checkbook register.  The register details are in a csv file:

```
date,chk num,description,amount,cleared state
```

Also, the csv file is a combination of a personal checkbook and the downloaded transactions from a bank. Ideally there are two copies of each record: one from the checkbook and one from the bank.  In reality there are some bank records that do not appear in the checkbook list and some other oddities.

If I were doing this in `perl` then I'd have a hash of hashes for each level of uniqueness.  I am trying to use `dicts` here though and have hit an issue with key values.  Specifically, my first uniqueness key is the amount of a transaction.  This could be a positive or negative float with exactly two decimal digits and no thousands separator: a la 1234567.89 or -0.24, etc

```
import csv

with open('C:/my/bank/docs/combined.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

    for row in reader:
        #
        # value
        if dataset.get(row[3]) != None:
...
```

It turns out that the first value in the file is -2844.29.  I get a `keyError` on the `if dataset.get(row[3]) != None:` line.  It complains about the key "-2844.29".

The csv file does not "quote" the value so I assume it is being treated as a `float`.  I then try to convert it to `string` with

```
        if dataset.get('{:.2f}'.format(row[3])) != None:
```

but that tells me: `ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'`.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the type of your object using the `type()` function. E.g:

```
print(type(row[3]))
```

and you can also check the type of your keys in the `dataset` object to see if it matches.

Anyway, `csv.reader` doesn't cast the things it reads in the csv file. Your `row` object is a `list` of `str` and you don't need to cast it if your `dataset` keys are also `str`. The error you get is because you are trying to format a `str` using the `.f` code (which is actually dedicated to number types).

**BUT**

Your code should then have worked when you tried `dataset.get(row[3])`. I think your dataset is not correctly built (I can't see the initialisation of this object here) and you should try to display it entirely in order to see if it actually contains the key `-2844.29` as a String (you can check if your `dataset` actually contains keys of type `str` and not `float`.